# How do I write a function using dplyr that lets me perform different sets of computations?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset which I need to perform multiple operations on. Dataset is provided below:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
    pid   ENT   DUL   EXC   NER   PEA
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   574    13    12    13     8    13
2   575     9     0     8     4     9
3   576    14     9    14     1    14
4   577    14     3    13     2    14
5   578    13    10    11    12    14

structure(list(pid = structure(c(574, 575, 576, 577, 578), label = "pid", format.spss = "F4.0", display_width = 0L), 
               ENT = c(13, 9, 14, 14, 13), DUL = c(12, 0, 9, 3, 10), EXC = c(13, 8, 14, 13, 11), 
               NER = c(8, 4, 1, 2, 12), PEA = c(13, 9, 14, 14, 14)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The steps I need to perform involve multiples steps, which I am unfortunately too inexperienced to perform by myself.

1. Subset the dataset, such that only the id `pid` and the variables that will be used remains. In this example, the variables I need are `ENT`, `DUL`, `EXC`, `NER`, and `PEA`.
2. Compute a `total` variable that sums up everything except `pid`.
3. Compute a probability score for each of the variables, e.g., `ENT_p` = `ENT`/`total`, `DUL_p` = `DUL`/`total`, etc.
4. Compute the ln of the probability score obtained in step 3, e.g., `ENT_ln` = `log`(`ENT`)
5. Replace, in all `_ln` variables, infinity values with 0.

And this is the point I get stuck. My code up till here is as follows:

```
shannon <- function(x, id, vars) {
  x %>%
    dplyr::select(id, all_of(vars)) %>%
    mutate(total = rowSums(.[vars]), 
           across(all_of(vars), ~./total, .names = "{col}_p"), 
           across(ends_with("_p"), ~log(.), .names = "{col}_ln"), 
           across(ends_with("_ln"), ~replace(., is.infinite(.), 0))) %>% 
    setNames(gsub("_p_ln", "_plnp", names(.)))
  }
```

But I still need to do a couple more things, which I am unable to.

6. Multiply, for each set of variables, their probability score and the ln score (e.g., `ENT_plnp` = `ENT_p` * `ENT_ln`)
7. Sum all the `_plnp` variables and multiply by `-1` (e.g., `-1 * sum(ENT_plnp, DUL_plnp, EXC_plnp, NER_plnp, PEA_plnp))`

I need a dynamic function, able to take in varying number of variables because I will have to run this same function with different number of variables. Appreciate any help at all. I'm on my 4th day working on such a simple problem and am not getting to where I need to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function :

```
library(tidyverse)

shannon <- function(x, id, vars) {
  x %>%
    dplyr::select(id, all_of(vars)) %>%
    mutate(total = rowSums(.[vars]), 
           across(all_of(vars), ~./total, .names = "{col}_p"), 
           across(ends_with("_p"), ~log(.), .names = "{col}_ln"), 
           across(ends_with("_ln"), ~replace(., is.infinite(.), 0))) %>%
    rename_with(~sub('_p', '', .), ends_with('p_ln')) -> result
  
  
  bind_cols(result, 
            map_dfc(vars, ~result %>%
                      select(starts_with(paste0(.x, '_'))) %>%
                      transmute(!!paste0(.x, '_plnp') := .[[1]] * .[[2]])) %>%
              mutate(total_plnp = rowSums(.) * -1))
}

shannon(df, 'pid', c('ENT', 'DUL'))

#    pid   ENT   DUL total ENT_p DUL_p ENT_ln DUL_ln ENT_plnp DUL_plnp total_plnp
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
#1   574    13    12    25 0.52  0.48  -0.654 -0.734   -0.340   -0.352      0.692
#2   575     9     0     9 1     0      0      0        0        0          0    
#3   576    14     9    23 0.609 0.391 -0.496 -0.938   -0.302   -0.367      0.669
#4   577    14     3    17 0.824 0.176 -0.194 -1.73    -0.160   -0.306      0.466
#5   578    13    10    23 0.565 0.435 -0.571 -0.833   -0.322   -0.362      0.685
```

1. Replaced `setNames` with `rename_with`. Also I guess using `setNames` renaming was happening incorrectly.
2. Used `map_dfc` to multiply each set of variables and add as a new column.
3. Create a new column  `total_plnp` to sum all the 'plnp' columns and multiplying them by -1.

Comment: Thanks again. What is the significance of using ```rename_with``` over ```setNames```? Or is it simply preference? Also, for this line ```rename_with(~sub('_p', '', .), ends_with('p_ln')) -> result```, why is ```result``` "assigned" at the end instead of at the start and why would ```result <- rename_with(~sub('_p', '', .), ends_with('p_ln'))``` not work?

Comment: `rename_with` is more flexible than `setNames` since it allows to rename columns based solely on pattern in their names, or index i.e column numbers similar to other `dplyr` functions like `across` and `select`. Moreover, since you are already using `tidyverse`, `rename_with` is more suitable to use here I think. As far as `-> result` is concerned it is the same thing. You can also do `result <- x %>%.....`

Comment: I tried reversing assignment with ```result <- rename_with(~sub('_p', '', .), ends_with('p_ln'))``` but got an error ```Error in UseMethod("rename_with") : 
  no applicable method for 'rename_with' applied to an object of class "formula"```. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, you have to reverse at the beginning of the pipe and not at `rename_with` line. `result <- x %>%  dplyr::select(id, all_of(vars)).....rest of the code`

Comment: Thanks! Got it working. I am trying to understand how the code work line by line, hope you forgive the multiple questions. I am not really sure how ```map_dfc()``` works. Your explanation suggest the multiplication of each set of variables, but how does it work? Isolating the code produces a dataset that seems to generate 4 identical datasets, but now each variable name is appended with ```... 1```, ```... 2```, etc. It further pipes into ```select()``` which removes some columns. I guess most of the important parts happen in ```transmute()```, but I can't seem to figure out what it does.